# Django - Stream request from external site as received

Tags: python, django, python-requests

How can Django be used to fetch data from an external API, triggered by a user request, and stream it directly back in the request cycle without (or with progressive/minimal) memory usage?

**Background**

As a short-term solution to connect with externally hosted micro-services, there is a need to limit user accessibility (based off the Django application's authentication system) to a non-authenticated API. Previous developers exposed these external IPs in Javascript and we need a solution to get them out of the public eye.

**Requirements**

- We are not bound to using the **requests** library and are open to using any others if it can help speed up the response time.
- Responses from the external API may be somewhat large (5-10MB) and being able to shorten the request cycle (User request via Ajax > Django > External API > Django > User) is crucial.

Is this possible? If so, can you suggest a method?

```
from django.shortcuts import Http404, HttpResponse
import requests

def api_gateway_portal(request, path=''):
    # Determine whether to grant access

    # If so, fetch and return data
    r = requests.get('http://some.ip.address/%s?api_key=12345678901234567890' % (path,))

    # Return as JSON 
    response = HttpResponse(r.content, content_type='application/json')
    response['Content-Length'] = len(r.content)

    return response
```

*Please note* - I am fully aware this is a poor long-term solution, but is necessary short-term for demo purposes until a new external authentication system is completed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import requests

from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def api_gateway_portal(request, path=''):
    url = 'http://some.ip.address/%s?api_key=12345678901234567890' % (path,)
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
        (chunk for chunk in r.iter_content(512 * 1024)),
        content_type='application/json')

    return response
```

Documentation:

- [Body content workflow](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) (`stream=True` explained)
- [`StreamingHttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects)
- [`iter_content()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content)

Comment: Beautiful, cut the response time by over half. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thank You. It helped a lot. Just a Tip: using lower chunk sizes is better for starting download sooner.