# Django Filewrapper memory error serving big files, how to stream

Tags: python, django, file, download, streaming

I have code like this:

```
@login_required
def download_file(request):
    content_type = "application/octet-stream"
    download_name = os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, "video.avi")

    with open(download_name, "rb") as f:
        wrapper = FileWrapper(f, 8192)
        response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=blabla.avi'
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(download_name)
    # response['Content-Length'] = _file.size
    return response
```

It seems that it works. However, If I download bigger file (~600MB for example) my memory consumption increase by this 600MB. After few such a downloads my server throws:

> Internal Server Error: /download/ Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/home/matous/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 35, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "/home/matous/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 128, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/home/matous/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 126, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/matous/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py",
>   line 21, in _wrapped_view
>       return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/media/matous/89104d3d-fa52-4b14-9c5d-9ec54ceebebb/home/matous/phd/emoapp/emoapp/mainapp/views.py",
>   line 118, in download_file
>       response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=content_type)   File "/home/matous/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py",
>   line 285, in **init**
>       self.content = content   File "/home/matous/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py",
>   line 308, in content
>       content = b''.join(self.make_bytes(chunk) for chunk in value) MemoryError

What I am doing wrong? Is it possible to configure it somehow to stream it the piece by piece from hard-drive without this insane memory storage?

Note: I know that big files should not be served by Django, but I am looking for simple approach that allows to verify user access rights for any served file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use `StreamingHttpResponse` instead, that will help, it is exactly what you are looking for.

*Is it possible to configure it somehow to stream it the piece by piece from hard-drive without this insane memory storage?*

```
import os
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper #django <=1.8
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper #django >1.8

@login_required
def download_file(request):
   file_path = os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, "video.avi")
   filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
   chunk_size = 8192
   response = StreamingHttpResponse(
       FileWrapper(open(file_path, 'rb'), chunk_size),
       content_type="application/octet-stream"
   )
   response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)    
   response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
   return response
```

This will stream your file in chunks without loading it in memory; alternatively, you can use [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects),

> which is a subclass of `StreamingHttpResponse` optimized for binary
>   files.