# Download some files as one zipped archive

Tags: python, django

i have some pictures in project root folder and i want to make them available to download dynamically as zip archive.

All the pictures have same name but the difference is in sequence number at the end, So i tried to do this

```
def zip_files(name, iterat):
    temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(temp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for index in range(iterat):
        filename = name+"_"+str(index)+".jpg"
        archive.write(filename)
    archive.close()
    wrapper = FileWrapper(temp)
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.zip'
    response['Content-Length'] = temp.tell()
    temp.seek(0)
    return response
```

so i got errors in lines `response['Content-Length'] = temp.tell()` and `temp.seek(0)`

> Operation in closed file.

and when i comment those lines, the returned data to the ajax is empty (because this is triggered as an ajax request)

**Update**

I used the `NamedTemporaryFile` as following :

```
def zip_files(name, iterat):
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(temp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for index in range(iterat):
        filename = name+"_"+str(index)+".jpg"
        archive.write(filename)
    archive.close()
    wrapper = FileWrapper(temp)
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.zip'
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(temp.name, 'r')
    response['Content-Length'] = open(temp.name).tell()
    return response
```

now i have no errors in server side but the returned data to the ajax request still empty, in browser network tab all information added to `HttpResponse` are in the Response Headers as following:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.zip
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/zip
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 15:32:08 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.2
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` returns a file handle, not a file name.

This will close the file handle:

```
 archive.close()
```

Afterwards, the handle can't be used anymore. In fact, the file will be deleted from disk by closing it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile

So even if you could ask the result of `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` for its name, that wouldn't help.

What you need to do is ask for a temporary *file name* (instead of just the file). Then create a handle for this file name, write the data, close the handle. For the request, create a new file handle using the name.

The method `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` should work for you. Make sure you pass the option `delete=False`. You can get the path to the file from `temp.name`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile

This will leave the file on disk after the response has been sent. To fix this, extend the `FileWrapper` and overwrite the `close()` method:

```
 class DeletingFileWrapper(FileWrapper):
     def close(self):
         # First close the file handle to avoid errors when deleting the file
         super(DeletingFileWrapper,self).close()

         os.remove(self.filelike.name)
```

If the ZIP file is big, you also want to use `StreamingHttpResponse` instead of `HttpResponse` since the latter will read the whole file into memory at once.

**Update**

You're still using an illegal (closed) file handle here: `FileWrapper(temp)`

Correct code would be:

```
wrapper = DeletingFileWrapper(open(temp.name, 'b'))
```

And you need to use a method which takes a file name to determine the length because `open(temp.name).tell()` always returns 0. Check the `os` module.

See also:

- [Serving dynamically generated ZIP archives in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454/serving-dynamically-generated-zip-archives-in-django)
- [Django Filewrapper memory error serving big files, how to stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949022/django-filewrapper-memory-error-serving-big-files-how-to-stream)

Comment: can you help me with some details, I'm really confused here.